# Efficient way to Count Certain Grouped Values jQuery Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, grouping

I have an array of people. I want to get the counts of the entire list grouped by each Level and Gender combination. I want to store these results in separate variables that I can display whenever I want in any order.

For instance, get the count for Level B Males and store that in a variable, Level B Females and store that in a variable, and Level B Nonbinary, Level A Males, Level A Females, and Level A Nonbinary, and so on through other levels storing those in their own variables. If storing them in an array is better (and it probably is), the order stored should be Level A Male, Female, Binary down to level Z Male, Female, Binary.

Also, I would like the totals of each Level as well.

I wrote up some stuff in the jsfiddle using a filter, but I've only done Level A. It will be too many lines of code doing Level B, C, D, etc. I think it can be much shorter and cleaner using a loop or something. Can anyone help me find a more efficient method?
http://jsfiddle.net/cM94j/2/

```
var list ={"PEOPLE": [
    {  "name": "Bob",  "level": "A",  "gender": "F"},
        {  "name": "Sue",  "level": "B", "gender": "F"},
       {  "name": "Molly",  "level": "A", "gender": "M"},
       {  "name": "Joe",  "level": "B", "gender": "N"},
        {  "name": "Jack",  "level": "B",  "gender": "F"}
        ]};
```

Also, at most this list will have ~80 people and Levels A-H. Going off tangent, with those specs, would I be better off putting this data into a spreadsheet of some kind like excel. It's not a big enough project for a database. How would I output to a website if I do go that route? Should I be outputting these server-side instead of using jQuery?

Comment: If this information is coming from the database have it provide that information. Doing it yourself will be cumbersome as you discovered.

Comment: Unfortunately this information is not coming from a database. For perspective, the list will have at most ~80 people and have Levels A-H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pure JS implementation you may want to use:

```
var list ={"PEOPLE": [
    {  "name": "Bob",   "level": "A",  "gender": "F"},
        {  "name": "Sue", "level": "B", "gender": "F"},
       {  "name": "Molly", "level": "A", "gender": "M"},
       {  "name": "Joe",  "level": "B", "gender": "N"},
        {  "name": "Jack", "level": "B",  "gender": "F"}
        ]};
var counts = {};
var gender = {
  F : "Female",
  M : "Male",
  N : "Neutral"
};
for(var i = 0; i < list.PEOPLE.length; i++){
  var key = list.PEOPLE[i].level + "_" + list.PEOPLE[i].gender;
  if(!counts[key]) counts[key] = 0;
  counts[key]++;
}
//try printing out the result
for(var prop in counts){
  var subKey = prop.split('_');
  var level = subKey[0];
  var gen = subKey[1];
  $('#dir2').append("Level " + level + " " + gender[gen] + 
                     ": " + counts[prop] + "<br/>");
}
```

If you want to get the count of a combination (between level and gender), just build the `key` by the format: `level_gender` (the abbreviation of gender) and pass in the `counts` to get the count.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/cM94j/3/)

Comment: Thank you! And yes, thanks for bringing up the combination counts. I forgot I would need the totals of each level as well.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping can be done easily with [underscore's groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) method

```
var grp=_.groupBy(list.PEOPLE, function(person){ return person.level+'_'+person.gender });
```

grp would be

```
Object {A_F: Array[1], B_F: Array[2], A_M: Array[1], B_N: Array[1]}
```

unfortunately, you have no way to control the key order in a JS object.